# Deploying an MVC 5 app to Azure site: UseMicrosoftAccountAuthentication

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, oauth

I created a sample application on my live.com developer account and set the redirect url to: http://msaccounttest.azurewebsites.net/signin-microsoft and updated the client id and secret on my mvc app. I have already tried and successfully tested this locally by applying multiple changes here and there since it is not possible to redirect to a localhost domain. However after deploynig it to my azure site and clicking on the microsoft button to log in I am redirected to ExternalLoginCallback with the following message:

> Error. An error occurred while processing your request.

I'd appreciate any input on this. Thanks.

EDIT: it could be due the a wrong database string, since even when registering a new user the same message appears.

Answer (score 0):

If someone is facing the same situation. After setting the custom error to false in the web.config file, as expected, it turned out to be an sql connection problem. After setting the default connection string to an Azure SQL database one and enabling the 1433 port from my firewall settings it is now working.